# Is there a way to control dispay order of forms when they have TopLevel property to false?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

(VB.net, Winforms)

I have a main form A which creates a Form B. And B creates another form C. Both B and C have the TopLevel property to false. Is there a way to control the order of the forms B and C. I need C to be always on top of B.

I tried all the following techniques but none of them works:

- Setfocus to C when it's losing it (Lostfocus event) ;
- Setfocus to C when B gets focus;
- Set C parent property to B but then C is created within B which is not what I really want.

Does anyone have an idea ?

thanks

Comment: I think rather than setting the Parent property, you need to set the Owner property of Form C to Form B.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't really work. I'm getting the error: Only top-level controls can have an owner. Since B has the Top Level property to false !

Comment: Why have you set TopLevel to false?